# Lua patterns returning nil

Tags: regex, lua, lua-patterns

This match is returning as nil, even in my eyes is okay. `string:match("^This boots belongs to the player (.-)%.$")`

The string is

`legendary boots.
    It can only be wielded properly by players of level 70 or higher.
    It weighs 8.00 oz.
    This boot has less regeneration than a soft boots, but it is infinite.
    This boots belongs to the player Administrador.`

It should returns the player name "Administrador", but always return as nil. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lua, as it seems, doesn't provide a method to receive different flags in order to change behaviors of some anchors / tokens. Saying that, `^` means start of string not start of line. Just remove it.